# Update recently added column in script

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have this script that is supposed to add column, update it from values from other column, delete that other column, and then rename the new column.

Here is what I have:

```
ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp ADD NumberOfCredit decimal(18,4) DEFAULT(0) NOT NULL

UPDATE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp
SET NumberOfCredit = convert(decimal(18,4), NumberOfCredits)

ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp DROP COLUMN NumberOfCredits

EXEC sp_RENAME 'Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp.NumberOfCredit', 'NumberOfCredits', 'Column'
```

The problem is when I try to run it I get the following, which I guess is because technically the column doesn't really exist. Yes, I've tried running and it simply won't run so it's not the intellisense messing with me.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'NumberOfCredit'.
```

Comment: is it `NumberOfCredits` , or `NumberOfCredit `?

Comment: So the current column is NumberOfCredits, but it's data type is int, and i cannot simply change to decimal, at least not that I am aware of, so as to not conflict with name I first add column that is NumberOfCredit, and then at end rename it once I have copied the data and dropped the old column

Comment: Can you run the first alter statement and then run the rest of the script separately?

Comment: I could, but that isn't what I want/need to do. This is all part of a larger script that makes all the changes to Live DB that were made in current sprint to DevDB, so really it needs to run all toghether.

Comment: i would opt for clearer naming conventions. I'm not sure why you have a NumberOfCredit and a NumberOfCredits ,

Comment: @Coffee the end result doesn't have both...as I explained the one without the s eventually gets renamed to have the s, it's just temp while I copy the data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a GO on the line after the first ALTER:

```
ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp ADD NumberOfCredit decimal(18,4)
GO

UPDATE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp
SET NumberOfCredit = convert(decimal(18,4), NumberOfCredits)

ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp DROP COLUMN NumberOfCredits

EXEC sp_RENAME 'Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp.NumberOfCredit', 'NumberOfCredits', 'Column'
```

Comment: That little word made all the difference, worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Just put a "Go" before Update . it will work  because DDL statement is not yet commited .

```html
    ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp ADD NumberOfCredit decimal(18,4)
go

UPDATE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp
SET NumberOfCredit = convert(decimal(18,4), NumberOfCredits)

ALTER TABLE Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp DROP COLUMN NumberOfCredits

EXEC sp_RENAME 'Certification.ProductEducationCreditTypeTemp.NumberOfCredit', 'NumberOfCredits', 'Column'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you can't alter the column in place?  I can understand using a migration script if you need to batch it to control log growth and the like, but you don't seem to be doing that.

ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN works just fine.

Here is a fiddle to show it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/442f6/12/0

As above, careful of your data sizes and log expansion.